# Powershell Invoke-Command executing on local, rather than remote server

Tags: powershell

I have a script that copies another script to a remote server then executes the 2nd script. This was working ok last week but today execution of the first script failed saying the 2nd script couldn't be found. As part of troubleshooting I created a simple version of the 2nd script (containing only Write-Host "Wrong Server!) on the local server. Now when I run the 1st script, the dummy 2nd script is executed on the local server!

I have pasted by test-harness script below:

```
$DeploymentFolderOnTargetServer = "c:\biztalkdeployment"

$TargetServer = "d-vasbiz01"                
$Username = "TFS_Service"
$Password = "x"
$SecPass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username,$SecPass
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $TargetServer -Authentication CredSSP -Credential $Cred
$Environment = "Dev"
$ExecuteScriptFilePath = join-path "$DeploymentFolderOnTargetServer" "ExecuteBizTalkAppMSI.ps1"
$MSI = "bin\debug\x.int.mis-3.0.0.msi"
$InstallFolderOnTargetServer = "C:\Program Files (x86)\x.Int.MIS for BizTalk 2010\3.0"

Write-Host "Session = $Session"
Write-Host "ExecuteScriptFilePath = $ExecuteScriptFilePath"
Write-Host "MSI = $MSI"
Write-Host "InstallFolderOnTargetServer = $InstallFolderOnTargetServer"
Write-Host "Environment = $Environment"
Write-Host "DeploymentFolderOnTargetServer = $DeploymentFolderOnTargetServer"


Invoke-Command -Session $Session  -FilePath $ExecuteScriptFilePath -argumentlist $MSI, $InstallFolderOnTargetServer, $Environment, $DeploymentFolderOnTargetServer
```

The output from the test is as follows:

```
Session = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession
ExecuteScriptFilePath = c:\biztalkdeployment\ExecuteBizTalkAppMSI.ps1
MSI = bin\debug\x.int.mis-3.0.0.msi
InstallFolderOnTargetServer = C:\Program Files (x86)\Vasanta.Int.MIS for BizTalk 2010\3.0
Environment = Dev
DeploymentFolderOnTargetServer = c:\biztalkdeployment
Wrong Server!
```

If I run get-session then the Computer Name for the session is correctly pointing at the 2nd Server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rather then troubleshoot with `Write-Host "wrong server"` try `Write-Host (hostname.exe)` to make sure which machine the second script executes on.  Also, the `-FilePath` parameter to `Invoke-Command` is specifying a *local* path to a script - not a path on the target computer.  `Invoke-Command` will take care of getting the local script file over to the target computer so that it can execute there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Keith. I will try this in the morning. Can I confirm, -FilePath should point to a local file? That is counter to my understanding so may be where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Yes, `-FilePath` should point to a local file or to a location the local computer can access (ie you can use a network share).  Check out the help topic on Invoke-Command for more info. http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849719.aspx

Comment: That was it Keith! Once you'd highlighted that Invoke-Command will copy the script to the target computer then everything fell into place. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem.  I copied the relevant comment into a proposed answer to this question for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-FilePath` parameter to `Invoke-Command` is specifying a **local** path to a script - not a path on the target computer. `Invoke-Command` will take care of getting the local script file over to the target computer so that it can execute there.